# ftp directory download triggers maximum call stack exceeded error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm currently working on a backup script with NodeJS. The script downloads a directory and its files und subdirectories recursively using FTP/FTPS. I'm using the [basic-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp) package to do the FTP calls.

When I try to download a big directory with a lot of subdirectories, I get the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error, but I don't find why and where it happens. I don't see any infinity loop or any missing return calls. After hours of debugging, I have no more ideas.

I don't use the `downloadDirTo` method from basic-ftp, because I don't want to stop downloading after a error happend. When an error occures it should keep going and it should add the error to the log file.

The repository is here: https://github.com/julianpoemp/webspace-backup.

As soon as the FTPManager is ready, I call the doBackup method (see method in BackupManager). This method calls the downloadFolder method defined in FTPManager.

```
export class BackupManager {

    private ftpManager: FtpManager;

    constructor() {
        osLocale().then((locale) => {
            ConsoleOutput.info(`locale is ${locale}`);
            moment.locale(locale);
        }).catch((error) => {
            ConsoleOutput.error(error);
        });

        this.ftpManager = new FtpManager(AppSettings.settings.backup.root, {
            host: AppSettings.settings.server.host,
            port: AppSettings.settings.server.port,
            user: AppSettings.settings.server.user,
            password: AppSettings.settings.server.password,
            pasvTimeout: AppSettings.settings.server.pasvTimeout
        });

        this.ftpManager.afterManagerIsReady().then(() => {
            this.doBackup();
        }).catch((error) => {
            ConsoleOutput.error(error);
        });
    }

    public doBackup() {
        let errors = '';
        if (fs.existsSync(path.join(AppSettings.appPath, 'errors.log'))) {
            fs.unlinkSync(path.join(AppSettings.appPath, 'errors.log'));
        }
        if (fs.existsSync(path.join(AppSettings.appPath, 'statistics.txt'))) {
            fs.unlinkSync(path.join(AppSettings.appPath, 'statistics.txt'));
        }
        const subscr = this.ftpManager.error.subscribe((message: string) => {
            ConsoleOutput.error(`${moment().format('L LTS')}: ${message}`);
            const line = `${moment().format('L LTS')}:\t${message}\n`;
            errors += line;
            fs.appendFile(path.join(AppSettings.appPath, 'errors.log'), line, {
                encoding: 'Utf8'
            }, () => {
            });
        });

        let name = AppSettings.settings.backup.root.substring(0, AppSettings.settings.backup.root.lastIndexOf('/'));
        name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const downloadPath = (AppSettings.settings.backup.downloadPath === '') ? AppSettings.appPath : AppSettings.settings.backup.downloadPath;

        ConsoleOutput.info(`Remote path: ${AppSettings.settings.backup.root}\nDownload path: ${downloadPath}\n`);

        this.ftpManager.statistics.started = Date.now();
        this.ftpManager.downloadFolder(AppSettings.settings.backup.root, path.join(downloadPath, name)).then(() => {
            this.ftpManager.statistics.ended = Date.now();
            this.ftpManager.statistics.duration = (this.ftpManager.statistics.ended - this.ftpManager.statistics.started) / 1000 / 60;

            ConsoleOutput.success('Backup finished!');
            const statistics = `\n-- Statistics: --
Started: ${moment(this.ftpManager.statistics.started).format('L LTS')}
Ended: ${moment(this.ftpManager.statistics.ended).format('L LTS')}
Duration: ${this.ftpManager.getTimeString(this.ftpManager.statistics.duration * 60 * 1000)} (H:m:s)

Folders: ${this.ftpManager.statistics.folders}
Files: ${this.ftpManager.statistics.files}
Errors: ${errors.split('\n').length - 1}`;

            ConsoleOutput.log('\n' + statistics);
            fs.writeFileSync(path.join(AppSettings.appPath, 'statistics.txt'), statistics, {
                encoding: 'utf-8'
            });
            if (errors !== '') {
                ConsoleOutput.error(`There are errors. Please read the errors.log file for further information.`);
            }
            subscr.unsubscribe();
            this.ftpManager.close();
        }).catch((error) => {
            ConsoleOutput.error(error);
            this.ftpManager.close();
        });
    }
}
```

```
import * as ftp from 'basic-ftp';
import {FileInfo} from 'basic-ftp';
import * as Path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {FtpEntry, FTPFolder} from './ftp-entry';
import {ConsoleOutput} from './ConsoleOutput';
import moment = require('moment');

export class FtpManager {
    private isReady = false;
    private _client: ftp.Client;
    private currentDirectory = '';

    public readyChange: Subject<boolean>;
    public error: Subject<string>;
    private connectionOptions: FTPConnectionOptions;

    public statistics = {
        folders: 0,
        files: 0,
        started: 0,
        ended: 0,
        duration: 0
    };

    private recursives = 0;

    constructor(path: string, options: FTPConnectionOptions) {
        this._client = new ftp.Client();
        this._client.ftp.verbose = false;
        this.readyChange = new Subject<boolean>();
        this.error = new Subject<string>();
        this.currentDirectory = path;
        this.connectionOptions = options;


        this.connect().then(() => {
            this.isReady = true;
            this.gotTo(path).then(() => {
                this.onReady();
            }).catch((error) => {
                ConsoleOutput.error('ERROR: ' + error);
                this.onConnectionFailed();
            });
        });
    }

    private connect(): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this._client.access({
                host: this.connectionOptions.host,
                user: this.connectionOptions.user,
                password: this.connectionOptions.password,
                secure: true
            }).then(() => {
                resolve();
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }

    private onReady = () => {
        this.isReady = true;
        this.readyChange.next(true);
    };

    private onConnectionFailed() {
        this.isReady = false;
        this.readyChange.next(false);
    }

    public close() {
        this._client.close();
    }

    public async gotTo(path: string) {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.isReady) {
                ConsoleOutput.info(`open ${path}`);
                this._client.cd(path).then(() => {
                    this._client.pwd().then((dir) => {
                        this.currentDirectory = dir;
                        resolve();
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
            } else {
                reject(`FTPManager is not ready. gotTo ${path}`);
            }
        });
    }

    public async listEntries(path: string): Promise<FileInfo[]> {
        if (this.isReady) {
            return this._client.list(path);
        } else {
            throw new Error('FtpManager is not ready. list entries');
        }
    }

    public afterManagerIsReady(): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.isReady) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                this.readyChange.subscribe(() => {
                        resolve();
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    },
                    () => {
                    });
            }
        });
    }

    public async downloadFolder(remotePath: string, downloadPath: string) {
        this.recursives++;

        if (this.recursives % 100 === 99) {
            ConsoleOutput.info('WAIT');
            await this.wait(0);
        }

        if (!fs.existsSync(downloadPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(downloadPath);
        }

        try {
            const list = await this.listEntries(remotePath);
            for (const fileInfo of list) {
                if (fileInfo.isDirectory) {
                    const folderPath = remotePath + fileInfo.name + '/';
                    try {
                        await this.downloadFolder(folderPath, Path.join(downloadPath, fileInfo.name));
                        this.statistics.folders++;
                        ConsoleOutput.success(`${this.getCurrentTimeString()}===> Directory downloaded: ${remotePath}\n`);
                    } catch (e) {
                        this.error.next(e);
                    }
                } else if (fileInfo.isFile) {
                    try {
                        const filePath = remotePath + fileInfo.name;
                        if (this.recursives % 100 === 99) {
                            ConsoleOutput.info('WAIT');
                            await this.wait(0);
                        }
                        await this.downloadFile(filePath, downloadPath, fileInfo);
                    } catch (e) {
                        this.error.next(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            this.error.next(e);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public async downloadFile(path: string, downloadPath: string, fileInfo: FileInfo) {
        this.recursives++;
        if (fs.existsSync(downloadPath)) {
            const handler = (info) => {
                let procent = Math.round((info.bytes / fileInfo.size) * 10000) / 100;
                if (isNaN(procent)) {
                    procent = 0;
                }
                let procentStr = '';
                if (procent < 10) {
                    procentStr = '__';
                } else if (procent < 100) {
                    procentStr = '_';
                }
                procentStr += procent.toFixed(2);

                ConsoleOutput.log(`${this.getCurrentTimeString()}---> ${info.type} (${procentStr}%): ${info.name}`);
            };

            if (this._client.closed) {
                try {
                    await this.connect();
                } catch (e) {
                    throw new Error(e);
                }
            }
            this._client.trackProgress(handler);
            try {
                await this._client.downloadTo(Path.join(downloadPath, fileInfo.name), path);
                this._client.trackProgress(undefined);
                this.statistics.files++;
                return true;
            } catch (e) {
                throw new Error(e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error('downloadPath does not exist');
        }
    }

    public chmod(path: string, permission: string): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this._client.send(`SITE CHMOD ${permission} ${path}`).then(() => {
                console.log(`changed chmod of ${path} to ${permission}`);
                resolve();
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }

    public getCurrentTimeString(): string {
        const duration = Date.now() - this.statistics.started;
        return moment().format('L LTS') + ' | Duration: ' + this.getTimeString(duration) + ' ';
    }

    public getTimeString(timespan: number) {
        if (timespan < 0) {
            timespan = 0;
        }

        let result = '';
        const minutes: string = this.formatNumber(this.getMinutes(timespan), 2);
        const seconds: string = this.formatNumber(this.getSeconds(timespan), 2);
        const hours: string = this.formatNumber(this.getHours(timespan), 2);

        result += hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

        return result;
    }

    private formatNumber = (num, length): string => {
        let result = '' + num.toFixed(0);
        while (result.length < length) {
            result = '0' + result;
        }
        return result;
    };

    private getSeconds(timespan: number): number {
        return Math.floor(timespan / 1000) % 60;
    }

    private getMinutes(timespan: number): number {
        return Math.floor(timespan / 1000 / 60) % 60;
    }

    private getHours(timespan: number): number {
        return Math.floor(timespan / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    }

    public async wait(time: number): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
            }, time);
        });
    }
}


export interface FTPConnectionOptions {
    host: string;
    port: number;
    user: string;
    password: string;
    pasvTimeout: number;
}
```

Comment: Inside the `FtpManager.downloadFolder` function, I see recursive calls to the same `downloadFolder` method with an `await`. It could come from there. Instead of `await`ing everything, you should setup a queue system. Something like this: Download every file in the folder, and add each subfolder found to a global queue and return. Then, process the queue progressively...

Comment: hm... that sounds good. I think about it. Thanks!

Comment: @blex how could such queue system look like? Is there any keyword I can look for?

Comment: I'll post an answer with a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. It's the pkg package that emits the maximum callstack exceeded error: [www.github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/681](http://www.github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/681).

When I test it directly using node on windows, it work's. I will either downgrade to Node 10 or looking for another solution.

Thanks @blex for the help!

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

Inside the `FtpManager.downloadFolder` function, I see recursive calls to the same `downloadFolder` method with an `await`. Your `Maximum call stack exceeded` error could come from there, since your initial call will need to keep everything in memory while traversing all subdirectories.

#### Proposed solution

Instead of `await`ing everything recursively, you could setup a queue system, with an algorithm like this:

- Add the current folder to a queue
- While that queue is not empty:

  - Get the first folder in the queue *(and remove it from it)*
  - List all entries in it
  - Download all files
  - Add all subfolders to the queue

This allows you to download a lot of folders in a loop, instead of using recursion. Each loop iteration will run independently, meaning that the result of the root directory download won't depend on the deeeeeep file tree inside it.

#### Using a queue manager

There are plenty of queue manager modules for NodeJS, which allow you to have concurrency, timeouts, etc. One I've used in the past is simply named [queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue). It has a lot of useful features, but will require a little more work to implement in your project. Hence, for this answer, I used no external queue module, so that you can see the logic behind it. Feel free to search for `queue`, `job`, `concurrency`...

#### Example

I wanted to implement that logic directly into your own code, but I don't use Typescript, so I thought I'd make a simple folder copy function, which uses the same logic.

**Note:** For simplicity, I've not added any error handling, this is just a proof of concept! You can find a demo project which uses this [here on my Github](https://github.com/blex41/non-recursive-folder-copy).

Here is how I've done it:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const Path = require('path');

class CopyManager {
  constructor() {
    // Create a queue accessible by all methods
    this.folderQueue = [];
  }

  /**
   * Copies a directory
   * @param {String} remotePath
   * @param {String} downloadPath
   */
  async copyFolder(remotePath, downloadPath) {
    // Add the folder to the queue
    this.folderQueue.push({ remotePath, downloadPath });
    // While the queue contains folders to download
    while (this.folderQueue.length > 0) {
      // Download them
      const { remotePath, downloadPath } = this.folderQueue.shift();
      console.log(`Copy directory: ${remotePath} to ${downloadPath}`);
      await this._copyFolderAux(remotePath, downloadPath);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Private internal method which copies the files from a folder,
   * but if it finds subfolders, simply adds them to the folderQueue
   * @param {String} remotePath
   * @param {String} downloadPath
   */
  async _copyFolderAux(remotePath, downloadPath) {
    await fs.mkdir(downloadPath);
    const list = await this.listEntries(remotePath);
    for (const fileInfo of list) {
      if (fileInfo.isDirectory) {
        const folderPath = Path.join(remotePath, fileInfo.name);
        const targetPath = Path.join(downloadPath, fileInfo.name);
        // Push the folder to the queue
        this.folderQueue.push({ remotePath: folderPath, downloadPath: targetPath });
      } else if (fileInfo.isFile) {
        const filePath = Path.join(remotePath, fileInfo.name);
        await this.copyFile(filePath, downloadPath, fileInfo);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Copies a file
   * @param {String} filePath
   * @param {String} downloadPath
   * @param {Object} fileInfo
   */
  async copyFile(filePath, downloadPath, fileInfo) {
    const targetPath = Path.join(downloadPath, fileInfo.name);
    console.log(`Copy file: ${filePath} to ${targetPath}`);
    return await fs.copy(filePath, targetPath);
  }

  /**
   * Lists entries from a folder
   * @param {String} remotePath
   */
  async listEntries(remotePath) {
    const fileNames = await fs.readdir(remotePath);
    return Promise.all(
      fileNames.map(async name => {
        const stats = await fs.lstat(Path.join(remotePath, name));
        return {
          name,
          isDirectory: stats.isDirectory(),
          isFile: stats.isFile()
        };
      })
    );
  }
}

module.exports = CopyManager;
```

Comment: I'm using your solution in my project, but the error still appears. What is really strange: The more lines I log to the console via ``console.log()`` the earlier the error message occurs... can this be right?

Comment: Sorry to hear that... This sounds weird, console logs shouldn't impact the call stack. I downloaded your project and tried it (very nice to use, btw). I launched a Docker FTP server and generated 30 levels of folders inside it, for a total of ~460 folders and ~460 files in them (made [this dirty script](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/tvWbUvQK)). I started your script, but it worked fine, I never met the stack limit. Can you tell me the level count, folder count and file count you have when you meet this limit?

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it very much. Sadly I still can't reproduce it exactly. Some times it occurs after 1 hour, some times after 4 hours. I try to backup an ownloud folder with over 40GB. There are a lot of subdirectories. I retry it again and try to enumerate the number of levels. I think it's about 12 levels min.

Comment: Maybe your stack trace will also help figure out where recursion is happening. If you can log it, it could be useful

Comment: you are right. I try to find out where the error is thrown, but it's difficult. I tried it before, but it was never catched... I will try to add more catch blocks.

Comment: the error from the last attempt: (node:3536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
(node:3536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3536) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: this time the level was only 4 and the error occured after 51 minutes...

Comment: Unfortunately, the is no stack trace here, which is weird. The only uncaught promise I can find by looking at the code is [this one](https://github.com/julianpoemp/webspace-backup/blob/master/src/obj/ftp-manager.ts#L190), but I don't see this method used anywhere as of now?

Comment: you're right, the getFolder function is an old one and is curently not used... I'm currently improving the code and adding more comments...

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find where this is coming from. This kind of problem is hard to debug/solve when it takes hours to reproduce, unless you have all the info you need in the logs. I took a look at your `ConsoleOutput.error` method. You colorize the message using this: `console.log(`\x1b[31m${message}\x1b[0m`)` but this is altering the message, and removing the stack trace, which is important info. I tried replacing it with a plain `console.log(message)` and voluntarily caused a skack overflow, the trace appeared. Maybe you should do this, at least until you find the origin of all this.

Comment: ok, thank you! I will continue looking for a solution. This problem has caused a headache for the last days and takes a lot of time, but I don't give up :)

Comment: I found the source of the problem. It's the pkg package that emits the maximum callstack exceeded error: https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/681
When I test it directly using node on windows, it work's! Do you want to add this information to your answer so I can mark it as solution?

Comment: Wow, nice find! You found the answer, I didn't :) You can answer your question yourself. Glad you could sort that out, it's been a long journey ;)